# Returning link to audio generated in Azure webservice

Tags: web-services, azure

I had been having problems trying to get my webservice working on azure but now the code appears to be running fine. ( I think ) 
I have the following simple speech generation code

```
 public speak()
{
    SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    synth.SetOutputToWaveFile("myfile.wav");
    synth.Speak("hello");
    synth.SetOutputToNull();
    synth.Dispose();
}
```

On my local Azure Emulator when I call this method I get UnauthorizedAccessException cannot access this location. How do I give the webservice running inside the Emulator privilages to writ to this location?

When running on Azure itself what must I do  so that I can return a URL to this file as the webservice is running inside its own environment and I have no idea how to get information/IP/DNS of this "instance" my code is running inside.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it will play the speech audio on the local hardware, in this case would be the VM within Microsoft Azure. This would be why you aren't getting it returned from the Web Service.

You'll need to output the speech audio to a file to be returned in the response from the Web Service method. It looks like [SpeechSynthesizer.SetOutputToWaveStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtowavestream(v=vs.110).aspx) may help with this.